# react-native can't use global variable in other js files

Tags: react-native

I defined an global variable, but it can't be defind at other js files , but the global variable 'storage' that I defined can use at other js files, they are all defined at index.android.js，please help me how to solve it?
[code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzU04.png)
[code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJZei.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I'd suggest adding to linked screenshots' code in the question.

Comment: All those consts that are declared in the constructor() should be declared above the class definition and change const to var if you are going to assign the variable later in the code.

Comment: you meet write like following?   `var  p = PixelRatio.get();
var dw = Dimensions.get('window').width*p;
var dh = Dimensions.get('window').height*p;
global.p = p;
global.dw = dw;
global.dh = dh;`   @Codesingh

Comment: which const you are using inside the render() ? (reference screenshot2)